# docker run with a project name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker Compose `name` allows to set a project name. So if I do something like

`name: my-project`

I'm getting something that looks like this:

[image: docker image]

How can I call `docker run` and place my container under this project name?
For instance if I do the following:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password1!" -p 1444:1433 --rm --name my-project/db -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest >nul
```

I get the following error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (my-project/db), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.
```

I am aware that my container is called `db`, I just don't know how to put it under the project name.

Comment: I don't think you can. At least not easily. The project name is used to let you run multiple sets of containers based on the same compose file. If you want to add a container to the configuration, you should add it to the compose file and do `docker compose up -d` again. Compose will see that a new container has been added and will start it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The `project-name` is a compose related feature [as the official Docker documentation says](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) to collect the started services/containers inside a compose file, and the "pure" Docker doesn't support it.

If you want to add a new container to (under)a project, then you should add the definition of service to the compose file. I think there is no other solution for it.

Comment: Here is the related Github ticket for it (Indicated the feature): https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1123